# Why do my 2 structs have different structure in debug watch?

Tags: c, struct, atmelstudio

I use 2 structs in my µC-project:

```
struct cRGB LED_OUTPUT[3] = {0};
struct LED_Object LEDS[3] = {0};
```

which are initiated in 2 separate header files as

```
struct cRGB  { uint8_t g; uint8_t r; uint8_t b; };
```

and

```
struct LED_Object{
         struct cRGB Color;
         uint8_t brightnessReduction;
         int8_t fadingDirection;
 ...}
```

In my debug watch window I get this view:
[image]

Why is LEDS[0] through [2] shown separately and LED_OUTPUT as one Object?
Because maybe that has to do with my problem when I enter a function and LED_OUTPUT is still visible in the Window and LEDS shows "Unknown Location".

Comment: maybe because the first struct is simple enough to be presented with one extra level?